# Honeybadger hook on Rails.logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I'd like to notify Honeybadger anytime I call Rails.logger, and have a ton of existing Rais.logger calls throughout my app.

Is there anyway to create a hook that is called each time Rails.logger.fatal is called?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to abuse the `formatter` for this. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#label-Format

Comment: Thanks so much - I've included an answer below as well

Comment: Just posted it - sorry for the delay - am a new member so apparently was not able to answer my own question for 8 hours. Appears to be working well.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up overriding the out of the box log formatter as follows:

```
class Logger::SimpleFormatter
  def call(severity, time, progname, msg)
    if Rails.env.production? && (severity == "FATAL" || severity == "ERROR")
        @context = { :severity => severity.to_s, :time => time.to_s, :msg => msg.to_s }
        Honeybadger.context(@context)
        Honeybadger.notify(@context)
    end
    return "[#{severity}] #{msg}\n"
end
```

end

Comment: Please don't do this.  The honeybadger gem uses the Rails logger to let you know when a call to the Honeybadger API fails, so if the API fails, you'll find your self in a loop with this.  Instead of monkey-patching Logger, you should send reports for errors you catch yourself like so: http://docs.honeybadger.io/article/32-log-ruby-exceptions-already-rescued